# Trying to call a function that is resting inside another function

Tags: javascript, html

I understand that this question has been asked before but none of the previous answers have helped me.

This is my function:

```
function execute() {
    console.log('here')
    const q = document.getElementById('myinput').value
    return gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
      "part": "snippet",
      "order": "viewCount",
      "q": q,
      "type": "video",
      "videoDefinition": "high",
      "maxResults": 10
    })
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log("Response", response);
          const z = response.result.items


         console.log("x", z)
          return(z.map(vid => {
            console.log("vid", vid)

            const date = document.createElement('div')
            const title = document.createElement('h2')
            const video = document.createElement('iFrame')


            date.textContent = vid.snippet.publishedAt
            title.textContent = vid.snippet.title



            const x = document.getElementById('results')
            console.log(date)
            x.append(date)
            x.append(title)
            x.append(video)


            const w = document.getElementById('date')
            const v = document.getElementById('view')
            function sorting(){

              const items = vid.childNodes;
              const itemsArr = [];
              for (var i in items) {
                if(items[i].nodeType == 1){
                  itemsArr.push(items[i])
                }
              }
              itemsArr.sort(function(a,b){
                return a.innerHTML === b.innerHTML
                    ? 0
                    : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
              });
              for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i){
                w.appendChild(itemsArr[i])
              }
          }
            return(x)


          }))

              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
```

I want to trigger that sorting function on my onclick: `<option  onclick="execute().sorting()"id = "date">Date</option>`

If you know how I can call it or even if you know a better way of sorting videos by date and view count, please leave a comment or answer. Any help is appreciated.

OH! I should add, this has to be done in pure vanilla javascript.

**Edit**

You asked for the HTML:

```
<button onclick="execute()">Search</button>
<h3>Sort:</h3>
<select>
  <option onclick="execute.b()"id="view" value="viewCount">View Count</option>
  <option  onclick="execute().sorting()"id = "date">Date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please part of HTML you're using in this javascript

Comment: @sarfraaztalat I added the HTML I believe you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor function with a nested function `sorting` scoped to this object when initiated, and then initiate it in js i.e.:

```
function Execute() {

this.search = function(){
    console.log('here')
    const q = document.getElementById('myinput').value
    return gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        "part": "snippet",
        "order": "viewCount",
        "q": q,
        "type": "video",
        "videoDefinition": "high",
        "maxResults": 10
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Response", response);
                const z = response.result.items


                console.log("x", z)
                return (z.map(vid => {
                    console.log("vid", vid)

                    const date = document.createElement('div')
                    const title = document.createElement('h2')
                    const video = document.createElement('iFrame')


                    date.textContent = vid.snippet.publishedAt
                    title.textContent = vid.snippet.title



                    const x = document.getElementById('results')
                    console.log(date)
                    x.append(date)
                    x.append(title)
                    x.append(video)


                    const w = document.getElementById('date')
                    const v = document.getElementById('view')

                    this.sorting();
                    return (x)


                }))

            },
            function(err) {
                console.error("Execute error", err);
            });
};

this.sorting = function() {

    const items = vid.childNodes;
    const itemsArr = [];
    for (var i in items) {
        if (items[i].nodeType == 1) {
            itemsArr.push(items[i])
        }
    }
    itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.innerHTML === b.innerHTML ?
            0 :
            (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
    });
    for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
        w.appendChild(itemsArr[i])
    }
};
```

}

Then create an instance when the whole page loads:

```
  var executeInstance;
  window.onload = function(event){
    executeInstance = new Execute();
  };
```

And in the HTML then call the instance (not sure what function `b` is, not present in initial example):

```
<button onclick="executeInstance.search()">Search</button>
<h3>Sort:</h3>
<select>
  <option onclick="executeInstance.b()"id="view" value="viewCount">View Count</option>
  <option  onclick="executeInstance.sorting()"id = "date">Date</option>
</select>
```

More on Object Constructor:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. For the new instance, should it be going inside or outside of the function? I assumed outside, and it is not working.

Comment: @IslaMcNeill, where do you include your javascript? within the `head` tag, or at the bottom before the closing `body` tag? Also, have you changed your html?

Comment: @IslaMcNeill, I have edited my answer, please try again